# Query optimisation with clustered column is not saving in billing "Bytes processed"

Tags: google-bigquery, cluster-analysis

**"Bytes billed" is same for 21k records read and 7.5Million records read.**

---

We have our **Google Analytics data exported into BigQuery tables** which creates one table per day with table names like "api-project.analytics.events_20231026"

There are 7.5 million records in "events_20231026" and I have enabled **clustering with column "event_name"**

Consider the following query...

```
SELECT  
  COUNT(event_name) as count
FROM 
  `api-project.analytics.events_*` 
WHERE 
  (_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20231026' AND '20231026')
```

[image]

- EXECUTION GRAPH says the query read **7.58 million records** from dataset
- The JOB INFORMATION tab says **Bytes billed as 111MB**

---

Now consider the query following query with filtering using the clustered field...

```
SELECT  
  COUNT(event_name) as count
FROM 
  `api-project.analytics.events_*` 
WHERE 
  event_name = 'purchase' AND 
  (_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20231026' AND '20231026')
```

[image]

- EXECUTION GRAPH says the query read **only 21k records** from dataset
- The JOB INFORMATION tab still says **Bytes billed as 111MB**

---

As you can see **filtering using a clustered field significantly reduced the number of record read but has no effect on the bytes billed.**

Any idea why this is happening? Could be a bug with the billing calculations in BigQuery ?

Thanks,

---

**UPDATE**

Avoiding **"*"** in table name and removing **_TABLE_SUFFIX** like the query below shows **Bytes processed as 316.76 KB only**

```
SELECT  
  COUNT(event_name) as count
FROM 
  `api-project.analytics.events_20231026` 
WHERE 
  event_name = 'purchase'
```

But in all practical purpose, we **will have to query the tables in a particular date range** and there should be reduced "Bytes processed" for billing. But as of now BigQuery assumes the cost of **full table read** even when the query shows far less records being processed.

Comment: What happens if you change the table name to `events_20231026`?  I think scanning the metadata for wildcard tables and `_table_suffix` might have some overhead. This might explain why it didn't change with your revised query.

Comment: @rtenha yes, you are correct... I updated the question with the behaviour when using direct table name. The issue is that the cost incurred when using wildcard is same as full data read... not  some metadata access cost difference.

Comment: Reading through the documentation (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables), it seems `_table_suffix` is treated as a column of some sort, so using the wildcard `*` still results in a scan of that column, which will incur a cost.

Answer (score 0):

Query multiple tables using a wildcard table
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables

According to the documentation above,

> "You can use wildcard tables with partitioned tables, and both
> partition pruning and cluster pruning are supported. However, tables
> that are clustered but not partitioned don't get any cluster pruning
> benefit from wildcard usage."

So, even if the tables are named based on the date, if there is no partitioning, the query benefit wont be there.

I created partitioned version of the table with the query below,

```
CREATE TABLE `api-project.analytics.events_partitioned_clustered_20231026`
PARTITION BY parsed_date
CLUSTER BY event_name
AS
SELECT
  *,
  PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date) as parsed_date
FROM `api-project.analytics.events_20231026`;
```

Now querying the new table with the same SQL,

```
SELECT  
  COUNT(event_name) as count
FROM 
  `api-project.analytics.partitioned_clustered_events_*` 
WHERE 
  event_name = 'purchase' AND 
  (_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20231026' AND '20231026')
```

- Shows the **Bytes processed as 517.16 KB**
- Tried multiple tables converted to (partitioned + clustered) ones and query on a date range also seems to be giving the saving.

Special thanks to @rtenha for the help.